# Не получается добавить class - Active элементу с его текущим названием elemActive

Tags: javascript

Дамы и Господа, пытаюсь написать функцию при клике которой элемент на который кликнули получил дополнительный `class` с его текущим названием класса, но получаю ошибку.  Не могу понять почему не работает....

Вот как выглядит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
  block[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    addClass(this);
    console.log(this);
  })
}

function addClass(elem) {
  //но если прописать строку ниже без elem
  // elem.classList.add('Active'); то все работает
  // но мне надо что бы именно не просто Active добавлялся 
  // а elemActive
  elem.classList.add(elem + 'Active');
  
  // когда попытался использовать метод который прописан ниже
  //  то отчасти понял в чем дело 
  // elem является object HTMLDivElement, если я конечно понял правильно
  
  //elem.className = elem + 'Active';
  // но вот как выйти из ситуации не соображу
}
```

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.block.blockActive {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам надо добавить класс elemActive, то его и добавляйте `elem.classList.add('elemActive');`. Зачем вы в функцию `add()`, которая принимает в качестве аргумента строку, пытаетесь передать ссылку на элемент?

Comment: @Pyramidhead потому что ему нужен не `elemActive`, а `blockActive`

Comment: @ThisMan, судя по комментарию `но мне надо что бы именно не просто Active добавлялся, а elemActive`, автор хочет `elemActive`. Либо он просто не может нормально излагать свои мысли.

Comment: @Pyramidhead стили и название переменных намекают именно на `blockActive`

Comment: Господа, я хочу, что бы функция у меня была универсальной...  Чтобы функция была универсальной...  Чтобы каждый элемент на который кликаешь получил дополнительно `class`...  Ну вот есть у него `class="zina"` что бы он получил   `class="zina zinaActive "`

Comment: @ThisMan, на стили не смотрел, да это и не так важно. На мой взгляд, `Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой` поэтому его следует закрыть.

Comment: @Pyramidhead, дорогой, ты где  в моем вопросе опечатку увидел?)))

Comment: Ну да опечатка  была тут `.block .blockActive {` с точки зрения `css`, должно быть без пробела, но к проблеме не имела ни какого отношения

Comment: @Air, во-первых, на "вы", пожалуйста. Во-вторых, я вам не "дорогой". В-третьих, я привёл лишь часть описания причины, по которой, на мой взгляд, вопрос стоит закрыть. Вот полное описание, если уж вы с ним не знакомы: "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса."

Comment: @Air, не разводите, пожалуйста, неуместных дискуссий. И не стоит полагать, что ваши странные нападки хоть кого-то задевают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `elem` хранится объект и при конкатенации вместо `elem` будет `[Object object]`

В вашем случае, что бы не париться и сделать все очевидным, просто добавьте второй параметр

```
const block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
  block[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    addClass(this, 'block');
  })
}

function addClass(elem, prefix) {
  elem.classList.add(prefix + 'Active');
}
```

Это чуть более явно показывает, что ожидать в результате от функции + если у элемента будет несколько классов ( `block some-class` ), то результат будет не таким, каким мы ожидаем ( `block some-classActive` )

Comment: Ну вот человек меня отлично понял)))  А говорят я вопрос не внятно описал))))  Благодарю....

Answer (score 1):

У Вас elem = [Object ...] при переводе в строку. Если Вы хотите чтобы получилось что-то типа 'blockActive' то, видимо, надо писать elem.className + 'Active'.

Comment: пытался так `JSON.stringify(elem)`   но не вышло

Comment: Зачем Вам JSON.stringify ??? Выведете в консоль consol.log(elem) и посмотрите какие свойства у него есть.

Comment: Чад,  благодарю, я понял о чем ты...

Answer (score 0):

В этой строке elem.classList.add(elem + 'Active'); - уберите "elem + "
оставьте

```
elem.classList.add('Active');
```

classList.add - не отменяет существующие классы, так же как и classList.remove
classList - работает только с тем классом, который вы ему передаёте

Answer (score 0):

Не просто `elem`, а  `elem.className`

```js
const block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
  block[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    addClass(this);
  })
}

function addClass(elem) {
  elem.classList.add(elem.className + 'Active');
}
```

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.block.blockActive {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Ну и свежий вариант

```js
const block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
block.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', () => e.classList.add(e.className + 'Active')))
```

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.block.blockActive {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```